unable to connect mongo-express
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
    # volumes:
    #   - ./database-data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: mypassword
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb:mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

This is .yml configuration file. Why it showing username and password again and again when i try to login in mongo-express ?

When you're using the environment variables,
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME : admin 
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD : mypassword

what you're doing is instructing the mongo-express on how to connect to mongodb server with the correct credentials.
However, the password and username that you get asked every time when you visit it from your browser are not your admin username and password. Instead its something called "web username" and "web password". These are used for log in to the mongo-express from your browser.
To set those you need to modify your environments in mongo-express container like follows
environment:
  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: mypassword
  ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: web_username
  ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: web_password
  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb

In this configuration, web_username and web_password are the credentials you should use when logging in from your browser.
For more details, refer to the official mongo-express documentation on docker hub.
